# How to create a new "person curve"?

Tags: graphics, image-processing, algorithm, wolfram-alpha-queries, generative-art

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) has a whole collection¹ of parametric curves that create images of famous people. To see them, enter `WolframAlpha["person curve"]` into a Mathematica notebook, or [`person curve` into Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=person%20curve&lk=1&a=ClashPrefs_*PlaneCurveClass.Person-). 
You get a mix of scientist, politicians and media personalities, such as Albert Einstein, Abraham Lincoln and PSY: [image: people]

The W|A parametric people curves are constructed from a combination of [trigonometric](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/TrigonometricFunctions.html) and [step](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitStep.html) functions. This suggests that the images might have been created by parametrising a sequence of contours... which is backed up by some curves being based of famous photos, e.g., the [W|A curve for PAM Dirac](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Paul%20Adrien%20Maurice%20Dirac%20curve&lk=1&a=ClashPrefs_*PlaneCurve.DiracCurve-):

[image]

is clearly based on the [Dirac portrait used in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Dirac):

[image]

Here's a animation showing each closed contour of Abraham Lincoln's portrait as the plot parameter $t$ increases by $2\pi$ units:

[image: Animated Abe]

Since the functions are so complicated, I can't believe that they were manually constructed. For example, the function to make Abe's bow tie is
(for $8\pi < t < 10\pi$)
[image: {x,y}=...]
The full parametric curve for Abe has 56 such curves tied together with step functions and takes many pages to display.

So my question is:

**How can I use *Mathematica* to take an image and produce a good looking "people curve"?**

Answers can start from [line art](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=line%20art%20portraits) and just automatically parametrise the lines or they can start from a [picture/portrait](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=famous%20portraits&tbo=u&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ei=hDLyUJSpB9CdiAeHyoGADA&ved=0CDIQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=714) and identify a set of contours that are then parametrised. Or any other (semi)automated approach that you can think of.

¹ <sub><sup>At the time of posting this question, it has 37 such curves.</sup></sub>

Comment: Could you please explain why you "can't believe that these were hand written"?

Comment: @belisarius: I've added an example of part of the output from `WolframAlpha["Abraham Lincoln curve", {{"EquationsPod:PlaneCurve", 1},
   "FormulaData"}]`. Not even the most downtrodden intern would be able to hand write such a mathematical function. Although, I admit, it could be hand traced and the traces parametrised - thus the line art comment in my question.

Comment: Given that the coefficients of $t$ inside the sinusoids are 1, 2, 3, ..., this is probably just the Fourier representation of a parametric curve. I'd guess they manually traced the curve as a polygon, took the discrete Fourier transform, and kept just enough of the lowest-order modes to make the curve look right. See also: [Ptolemy and Homer (Simpson)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVuU2YCwHjw).

Comment: @Rahul: I agree, so what's the code to perform the post-tracing part? Also, thanks for the youtube video!

Comment: In Wolfram Demonstration pages I have seen one that can segment an image for a given threshold. Please see http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SegmentingAMedicalImage/. Maybe it could be a departure point?

Comment: Another demonstration: [TracingContourLinesInPhotographicImages](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TracingContourLinesInPhotographicImages/) gets a handle on contour lines.

Comment: The method called "Fourier Descriptors" does something similar: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/preview.html?draft/46249/000012/FourierDescriptors

Comment: Strange mix of people available. Could you use `Sound` and `SoundNote` to play "Gangnum Style" with the PSY plot?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This now has been discussed in Wolfram blog posts by Michael Trott:

Part 1: [**Making Formulas… for Everything — From Pi to the Pink Panther to Sir Isaac Newton**](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/)
Part 2: [**Using Formulas... for Everything — From Complex Analysis Class to Political Cartoons to Music Album Covers**](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/06/10/using-formulas-for-everything-from-a-complex-analysis-class-to-political-cartoons-to-music-album-covers/)
Part 3: [**Even More Formulas… for Everything—From Filled Algebraic Curves to the Twitter Bird, the American Flag, Chocolate Easter Bunnies, and the Superman Solid**](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/08/15/even-more-formulas-for-everything-from-filled-algebraic-curves-to-the-twitter-bird-the-american-flag-chocolate-easter-bunnies-and-the-superman-solid/)

Here is one of the example apps from blog - go read it in full - fun! Don't miss the link to download the notebook with complete code and apps at the end of the blog.

[image: Newton Outline Manipulable]

Comment: Nice picture of Newton. But why does his shirt have so many buttons?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Newton was known to dress up in disguises and roam the streets of London in order to catch the counterfeiters. As Warden, and afterwards Master, of the Royal Mint, Newton estimated that 20 percent of the coins taken in during The Great Recoinage of 1696 were counterfeit. Counterfeiting was high treason, punishable by the felon's being hanged, drawn and quartered. Despite this, convicting the most flagrant criminals could be extremely difficult. However, Newton proved to be equal to the task. Disguised as a habitué of bars and taverns, he gathered much of that evidence himself.

Comment: Ironically, it was Newton himself who was drawn above. In portrait form, suitable for hanging in ones quarters. But I digress.

Answer (score 53):

This shows a way to parametrise a line using the method suggested by Rahul Narain in a comment, i.e. using `Fourier` to approximate the data with a set of sinusoids. I use `Rationalize` to convert all the reals back to rationals, this isn't necessary but it makes the expression look more like those used in Wolfram Alpha.

```
param[x_, m_, t_] := Module[{f, n = Length[x], nf},
  f = Chop[Fourier[x]][[;; Ceiling[Length[x]/2]]];
  nf = Length[f];
  Total[Rationalize[
     2 Abs[f]/Sqrt[n] Sin[Pi/2 - Arg[f] + 2. Pi Range[0, nf - 1] t], .01][[;; Min[m, nf]]]]]

tocurve[Line[data_], m_, t_] := param[#, m, t] & /@ Transpose[data]
```

`tocurve` will take a `Line`, a number of modes `m` and a symbolic parameter `t` and return a parametrisation of the line data. Because of the implied periodicity of the data in `Fourier` it will only work properly on closed lines.

The hard part is getting a good set of lines from the image of a person. Here's a much simpler example using `ListContourPlot` to extract the outline of a silhouette.

First load an image and do a bit of preprocessing to ensure a nice contour:

```
img = Import[
   "http://catclipart.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/elephant-silhouette-clip-art.gif"];

img = Binarize[img~ColorConvert~"Grayscale"~ImageResize~500~Blur~3]~Blur~3;
```

[image]

Now extract contours and plot the parametrised curve with 500 modes:

```
lines = Cases[Normal@ListContourPlot[Reverse@ImageData[img], Contours -> {0.5}], _Line, -1];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[tocurve[#, 500, t] & /@ lines], {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

With fewer modes the detail starts to smooth out. Here's the 30 mode curve:

[image]

The parametrisation consists of sinusoids:

```
curves // Short
```

[image]

Comment: That is pretty impressing! May I ask where curves comes from?

Answer (score 23):

This was supposed to be a comment to Simon's answer, but it's gotten too long. Still, I wanted to share a somewhat cleaned-up version of Simon's Fourier-fitting function `param[]` (which I have renamed to `FourierCurve[]`):

```
FourierCurve[x_, m_, t_, tol_: 0.01] := Module[{rat = Rationalize[#, tol] &, fc},
  fc = Take[Chop[Fourier[x, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]], Min[m, Ceiling[Length[x]/2]]];
  2 rat[Abs[fc]].Cos[Pi (2 Range[0, Length[fc] - 1] t - rat[Arg[fc]/Pi])]]
```

This has the virtue of returning a function that *genuinely closes up*; more precisely, if `f[t_] = FourierCurve[pts, modes, t]`, then `f[0] == f[1]`. (The indiscriminate use of `Rationalize[]` in the earlier version prevented a nice closure of the resulting curve.)

As Rahul alludes to in his comment, this is more or less the "epicycle" approach of Ptolemy for determining the paths of planetary orbits.

---

Of course, Fourier fitting can also be applied to **space** curves as well as plane curves. Here's an example:

```
{f[t_], g[t_], h[t_]} = FourierCurve[#, 20, t] & /@
                        KnotData["FigureEight", "SpaceCurve"]["ValuesOnGrid"];

ParametricPlot3D[{f[t], g[t], h[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False,
                 Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 20}, PlotStyle -> Blue, ViewPoint -> Top] /. 
Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 1/8, rest]
```

[image: figure-eight knot]

Since most of the knots given in `KnotData[]` have their space curves given as `InterpolatingFunction[]` objects, you can use this approach if you prefer to have explicit parametric expressions for those knots.

Comment: (This isn't yet my official return; I found some spare time and decided to exploit it.)

Comment: Spare time is hard to come by sometimes... I'll find some one day and come back to evaluating and accepting one of these answers

Answer (score 7):

Simon Woods' [cool answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17780/18767) is based on two independent discrete Fourier transforms: one for $x$, one for $y$. This answer differs in that it uses only one, but on complex values. It's it not a very big difference that is a required step for [this kind of things](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171755/how-can-i-draw-a-homer-with-circles/171756?noredirect=1#comment451143_171756).

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtJoA.png"];
img = Binarize[img~ColorConvert~"Grayscale"~ImageResize~500~Blur~3];
pts = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[Normal@ListContourPlot[Reverse@ImageData[img], 
       Contours -> {0.5}], _Line, -1][[1, 1]];

z = pts[[All, 1]] + I*pts[[All, 2]];
m = 10;
n = Length@z;
cn = 1/n*Table[Sum[z[[k]]*Exp[-I*i*k*2 Pi/n], {k, 1, n}], {i, -m, m}];
{f[t_], g[t_]} = {Re@#, Im@#} &@
    Sum[cn[[i + m + 1]]*Exp[I*i*t], {i, -m, m}] // ComplexExpand;
ParametricPlot[{f[t], g[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

- $m=10$:

[image]

- $m=20$:

[image]

To make the difference clear: Simon Woods' code with `m = 3` gives

```
{{4341/8 + 1593/8 Sin[37/11 + (44 t)/7] + 58 Sin[1/3 + (88 t)/7], 
  3225/11 - 867/8 Sin[6/5 - (44 t)/7] + 142/3 Sin[45/23 + (88 t)/7]}}
```

while the above code gives:

```
{23.2813 - 38.9784 Cos[t] + 16.5986 Cos[2 t] - 17.5251 Cos[3 t] - 
  195.161 Sin[t] + 55.6546 Sin[2 t] - 15.5714 Sin[3 t], -101.483 - 
  101.745 Cos[t] + 44.3024 Cos[2 t] - 34.0713 Cos[3 t] + 
  37.4785 Sin[t] - 16.4218 Sin[2 t] + 5.10139 Sin[3 t]}
```

The base functions are the same for `x` and `y` here.

*Note* If someone manages to compute my `cn` using `Fourier` I'd be happy!