# How to convert the binarize-picture to a Region

Tags: image-processing, image, regions

The `Region` of `Mathematica` is nice,and is the new conception of version 10.0.I can convenient get `Area`,`Centroid` and the `RandomPoint` from the `Region`.Now,I get a beautifull apple like this picture.

[image]

Then I `Binarize` it:

```
binapple = Binarize[pic, 0.91] // ColorNegate // FillingTransform
```

so I get the binarize-apple:
[image]

The question is how to convert the binarize-apple to a `Region`.Can anybody give some suggestion.I'll appreciate you sincerely.

Comment: Related, I believe: [(17704)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17704/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a partial answer which might lead you in the right direction.  If we convert the binarized image into image data, we can establish a condition suitable for `RegionPlot`:

```
rp = With[{idata = ImageData[binapple], 
  xmax = First@ImageDimensions[binapple], 
  ymax = Last@ImageDimensions[binapple]},
 RegionPlot[
  idata[[IntegerPart@(ymax - y), IntegerPart@x]] == 1, {x, 1, 
   xmax}, {y, 1, ymax}]]
```

[image]

The problem with this approach is that one *should* be able to create an implicit region in a similar manner, however I am getting a part specification error message when I try:

```
With[{idata = ImageData[binapple], 
  xmax = First@ImageDimensions[binapple], 
  ymax = Last@ImageDimensions[binapple]},
 ImplicitRegion[
  idata[[IntegerPart@(ymax - IntegerPart@y), IntegerPart@x]] == 1 && 
   1 <= IntegerPart@x <= xmax && 1 <= IntegerPart@y <= ymax, {x, y}]]
```

I'll certainly update this half-answer once I find my error.

**Note:** One hackish way to get the region itself is to run `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@rp[[1]]`.  We can wrap this all up in a function:

```
binaryImageToRegion[bimg_] := 
 With[{idata = ImageData[bimg], xmax = First@ImageDimensions[bimg], 
   ymax = Last@ImageDimensions[bimg]},
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@
   First@RegionPlot[
     idata[[IntegerPart@(ymax - y), IntegerPart@x]] == 1, {x, 1, 
      xmax}, {y, 1, ymax}]]
```

So that `binaryImageToRegion[binapple]` gives:

[image]

The `RegionPlot` does add quite a bit of overhead, but I don't see a significant performance issue with your test case.

Comment: ... and `binaryImageToRegion[binapple] // RegionQ` yields **True**.

Comment: I'm confuse why using ImplicitRegion,too.When you find the error,update it,please~^_^

Answer (score 7):

Another more or less direct construction, like [rherman's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/10397/rhermans):

```
Clear[square];
(* Create a square for each pixel in  pos  *)
square = Compile[{{pos, _Real, 2}},
   Block[{tp = Transpose[pos]},
    Transpose[
     {tp - 1, {tp[[1]], tp[[2]] - 1}, tp, {tp[[1]] - 1, tp[[2]]}},
     {2, 3, 1}
     ]
    ]
   ];

discretizeImage[img_] := Module[{pos, poly, coords, nf},
   pos = PixelValuePositions[img, 1];
   poly = square[pos];
   coords = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[poly, 1];
   nf = Nearest[coords -> Automatic];
   MeshRegion[
    N@coords,
    Polygon[poly /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> First@nf[{x, y}]]
    ]
   ];

mesh = discretizeImage[binapple // DeleteSmallComponents]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.90293, Null}  *)

bmesh = BoundaryMesh@mesh
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your Transpose and your MeshRegion impressed to me deeply.But considering the briefness and the running efficiency,I'll maintance my first acception still.Thanks very much all the same.

Comment: @yode You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkLgU.png"];

imgregion[im_] := 
 Polygon[Part[#, Last@FindShortestTour[#]] &@
   PixelValuePositions[
    MorphologicalPerimeter[
     Erosion[FillingTransform@ColorNegate@Binarize[im, 0.91], 2], 
     CornerNeighbors -> False], 1]]

RegionQ@imgregion[img]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
RegionPlot[imgregion[img]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics[imgregion[img]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your help.The FindShortestTour is a good stuff.But I think there is a the blemish in this way,such as the binarize-picture isn't a complete part which combine many "white".The FindShortestTour will be shy.and the FindCurvePath is a bug function I think.

Comment: +1. This is reasonably fast and avoids the problems of `RegionPlot` in the currently accepted answer (when it subdivides and is not just a proxy for `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`). --  Do you know about `PixelValuePositions`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about `PixelValuePositions`. Answer updated.

Comment: I was wandering if there was a good way to replace `Binarize`, for something more clever, incorporating the information that the area of interest is green, as the gray shadow is clearly not part of the apple. I'm aware of `ColorSeparate`, but that works only for `Green` `{0,1,0}` and in this case the dominant color is `{0.482, 0.700, 0.191}`.

Comment: @rhermans Do you mean the `ChanVeseBinarize`?