# How to plot customly-shaped set of 3D points each connected to its neighbors?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

Consider the following code:

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Flatten[#, 1] &@
  Table[{x, y, 1}, {x, 0, 5, 5/60}, {y, Sin[x], Cos[x] + 3, (
    Cos[x] + 3 - Sin[x])/60}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: point plot]

If I change `ListPointPlot3D` to `ListPlot3D`, I get the following:

[image: connected plot]

Apparently, `ListPlot3D` connects the points not in an expected way.

How to plot the set so that the neighboring points were connected with each other, not the far ones?

Comment: You want a plot that looks like this `RegionPlot3D[
 Sin[x] < y < Cos[x] + 3 && z == 1, {x, 0, 5}, {y, -1, 4}, {z, 0, 2}]`?

Comment: assuming this is a toy example, for the real problem do you know the underlying functional form for the region?

Comment: @george2079 in the real problem the points come from other sources, I don't know the region in general.

Comment: its actually quite a tough problem to find the non-convex boundary of a set of points. (If they are on a regular grid as in example that helps)

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124562/2079

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88752/delaunaymesh-in-a-specified-closed-region-creating-a-concave-hull-from-a-set-o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the points form a deformed rectangular grid, then you can use the method below;
otherwise, the methods of the following question should work:

[DelaunayMesh in a specified closed region - creating a concave hull from a set of points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88752/delaunaymesh-in-a-specified-closed-region-creating-a-concave-hull-from-a-set-o)

For a tensor grid of points:

```
pts = N@Table[{x, y, Cos[x] Sin[y]},  (* varying height *)
    {x, 0, 5, 5/60},
    {y, Sin[x], Cos[x] + 3, (Cos[x] + 3 - Sin[x])/60}];

With[{p = Flatten[pts, 1]},
 Graphics3D[
  GraphicsComplex[
   p,
   {EdgeForm[], ColorData[97][2],
    Polygon[
     Flatten[#][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]] & /@ Flatten[Partition[
        Partition[Range@Length@p, Length@First@pts],
        {2, 2}, {1, 1}],
       1]
     ]}
   ]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It works even better if the height is a constant `1`.

Answer (score 4):

You can restrict your PlotRegion in Plot3D

```
Plot3D[1,{x,0,5},{y,-1,4},RegionFunction->(Sin[#1]<#2<Cos[#1]+3&)]
```

> [image]

For more complicated Regions you should use RegionPlot3D.
Here is the restriction for all 3 dimensions (which creates a beautiful figure if you ask me):

```
RegionPlot3D[(Sin[x]<y<Cos[x]+3)&&(Sin[y]<z<Cos[y]+3)&&(Sin[z]<x<Cos[z]+3),{x,-1,4},{y,-1,4},{z,-1,4},MaxRecursion->10,PlotPoints->100]
```

> [image]

Comment: you can use the same `RegionFunction` with `ListPlot3D` as well

Answer (score 2):

`ListPlot3D` accepts `RegionFunction`, so let's exploit this fact. The idea is to create a region.

```
data = Flatten[#, 1] &@
  Table[{x, y, 1}, {x, 0, 5, 5/60}, {y, Sin[x], 
    Cos[x] + 3, (Cos[x] + 3 - Sin[x])/60}]

data2D = data[[All, 1 ;; 2]]

range = {{0, 5}, {-1, 4}}
```

First, `Binarize` the region

```
reg = Binarize@
  ListPlot[data2D, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize -> Large]
```

so that one can use the functions of [bobthechemist](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95549/22013) and [rhermans](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95606/22013):

```
binaryImageToRegion[bimg_] := 
 With[{idata = ImageData[bimg], xmax = First@ImageDimensions[bimg], 
   ymax = Last@ImageDimensions[bimg]}, 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@
   First@RegionPlot[
     idata[[IntegerPart@(ymax - y), IntegerPart@x]] == 1, {x, 1, 
      xmax}, {y, 1, ymax}]]

reg1 = binaryImageToRegion[ColorNegate@reg]
```

[image]

```
{100, 100} \[Element] reg1
{200, 200} \[Element] reg1
```

> False
>
> True

and

```
imgregion[im_] := 
 Polygon[Part[#, Last@FindShortestTour[#]] &@
   PixelValuePositions[
    MorphologicalPerimeter[
     Erosion[FillingTransform@ColorNegate@Binarize[im, 0.91], 2], 
     CornerNeighbors -> False], 1]]

reg2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@imgregion[reg];

plot = RegionPlot@reg2
```

[image]

```
{100, 100} \[Element] reg2
{200, 200} \[Element] reg2
```

> False
>
> True

I'll use `reg1` here; exactly the same results were obtained with `reg2`.

We need to translate the coordinates in `data`, which are in the `range`, so that they correspond to those in `reg1`. We need to take dimensions of the `RegionPlot` of `reg1`, without the `Frame`:

```
id = ImageDimensions @ RegionPlot[#, Frame -> None] &@reg1
```

> {360, 360}

I calculated it with pen and paper, but it's easy (the transformation is linear) to do it automatically. With the derived `RegionFunction`:

```
ListPlot3D[data, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, {72 x, (y + 1) 72} \[Element] reg1]]
```

[image]