# How to add a fading trail effect in Animate?

Tags: graphics, animation, parametric-functions, generative-art, version-7

I would like to add a smooth fading effect to the end of a curve, while it is animated.  Here's a minimal working example which shows a particle moving on a circle (the circle is drawn while the particle is moving around):

```
circle[t_] := {Sin[Pi t], Cos[Pi t]};
dMax = 1.5;

Animate[
  Show[
    {ParametricPlot[circle[t], {t, 0 + 0.001, T},
      PlotRange -> {{-dMax, dMax}, {-dMax, dMax}},
      Frame -> True, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotPoints -> 100],
     Graphics@{Black, PointSize -> 0.015, Point[circle[T]]}},
   ImageSize -> 500], 
 {T, 0, 6}, AnimationRate -> 1, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

1. The end of the trajectory should gently fade away while the particle is moving. Is it possible to do this animation effect with *Mathematica* (I'm using version 7.0)?
2. Also, I don't understand why I need to add a small delay `(0 + 0.001)` to the `Animate` definition. Without that delay, *Mathematica* gives an error message:

   > Endpoints for t in {t, 0+0., T} must have distinct machine-precision numerical values.

   So how to properly fix this problem without adding an arbitrary delay?

Comment: [75936](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75936/5478) [4847](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4847/5478)

Comment: Kuba, it is not the same.  What I'm asking is a fading effect on a part of the path drawn.  Not on the particle itself.

Comment: I'm not saying it is although I could argue since the trail after the point is continuous.

Comment: See the answer below.  It is great !

Comment: There are lot of useful approaches: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4847/1997

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100120

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ColorFunction` and `Epilog` were around in version 7.  However, `ColorFunction` did get an update in version 9 so I am not certain if this will work in version 7.

```
Animate[
 ParametricPlot[circle[t], {t, Max[0, u - .2], u}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-dMax, dMax}, {-dMax, dMax}},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, w}, Opacity[w, Blue]],
  Frame -> True, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotPoints -> 100,
  Epilog -> {Black, PointSize -> 0.015, Point[circle[u]]}],
 {u, 0. + $MachineEpsilon, 6}, AnimationRate -> 1, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, it's working !  Thanks.  I'll have to study your answer.

Comment: Why the small delay of 0.001 ?

Comment: My code appears to be working great !  :-)  However, I still don't understand the delay of 0.001.  Is it really necessary to add such an arbitrary delay to the animate defintion ?

Comment: @Cham It errors if I use `0` or `0.` as the start. Might be a bug.

Comment: A bug ?  Is it the same with your more recent version of Mathematica ?

Comment: Yes. Version 10.3.1 Win 8.1 Pro 64 bit. A `ParametricPlot` of `circle` can start at zero with no issues. It seems that `Animate` does not like it to start at zero.

Comment: The problem is you're trying to make a parametric plot from `{t,Max[0, u - .2],u}`. When `u=0`, `Max[0,u-0.2]` evaluates to `0`, then you're plotting from `{t,0,0}`, which parametric plot doesn't like.

Comment: @Evans, so what should be the proper way of parametrizing the animation ?  My only concern here is the **arbitrariness** of the 0.001 delay value I'm using.

Comment: @Cham You can use `0. + $MachineEpsilon` instead of `0.001`. This is the closest your computer can get to zero and a less arbitrary way of preventing `ParametricPLot` from plotting zero to zero.