# How to graph the contour of a resulting Manipulate curve

Tags: plotting, manipulate, fourier-analysis

How can the green contour be graphed?

[image]

```
FourierF[a_, t_] := a.Table[Sin[ 2 Pi i t], {i, Length[a]}];

FourierAnim[a_, t_] :=
  Module[{
    A = Accumulate[a*Table[Cos[ 2 Pi i t], {i, Length[a]}]],
    B = Accumulate[a*Table[Sin[2 Pi i t], {i, Length[a]}]]},
   PrependTo[A, 0]; PrependTo[B, 0];
   Show[
    Graphics[
     Table[
      {Circle[{A[[i]], B[[i]]}, a[[i]]],
       Darker[Red], 
       If[i != Length@a, 
        Line[{{A[[i]], B[[i]]}, {A[[i + 1]], B[[i + 1]]}}],
        {Red, Dashed, Line[{{A[[i]], B[[i]]}, {2, B[[i]]}}]}]

       (* next line needs to be fixed *)
       , {Green, Line[Table[{m, n}, {m, A[[i]], t}, {n, B[[i]], t}]]}
       (* end of section needing editing *)

       },
      {i, Length@a}
      ],
     PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 3}, {-1, 1}}
     ],
    Plot[FourierF[a[[;; -2]], t - \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 2, 3}]
    ]
   ];

a = Table[(1 - (-1)^i)/i, {i, 64}]/Pi;
(* (1+(-1)^i)/i,{i,65} for sawtooth wave *)
(* ??? for triangle wave *)

Manipulate[
 FourierAnim[
  a[[;; j]], t], {t, 0, 1}, {j, 8, Length@a, 2}
 ]
(* {t,0,0.5},{j,9,Length@a,2} for sawtooth wave *)
(* ??? for triangle wave *)
```

The code is a modified version of [the original](http://blog.matthen.com/post/42112703604/the-smooth-motion-of-rotating-circles-can-be-used); it demonstrates how the smooth motion of rotating circles can be used to build up any repeating curve.

The eventual solution was suggested by user [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) in a comment from the second related thread posted below.

> Can you make a list of the points and use `Line`? You seem to be able
>   to calculate the points at each time (in order to draw the figure).
>   Just make a `Table` of them over one period with suitable increment of
>   time.

One of the early attempts of coding this was left uncommented, because it is the only one that produced visible related results. I now understand the error in `Table` and the array it generates, but this example is perfect for showing the confusion of a beginner. The solution will help me a lot in learning through examples.

*Additional question:

What exactly needs to be changed in the formula `1-(-1)^i)/i` in order to make (an approximation of) a triangle wave?*

Comment: Closely related: [how-to-create-a-new-person-curve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/how-to-create-a-new-person-curve)

Comment: [Another related thread.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100051)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Generating the outline

By looking at the code we can infer that the position of the center of the outermost circle is given by

```
outline[a_, t_] := Module[{
   A = Accumulate[a Table[Cos[2 Pi i t], {i, Length[a]}]],
   B = Accumulate[a Table[Sin[2 Pi i t], {i, Length[a]}]]
   }, {Last[A], Last[B]}]
```

This code comes straight from the one you posted; each element in `A` and `B` are the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the subsequent circles. The last elements represent the positions of the outermost circle.

We can now plot the outline using `ParametricPlot`:

```
a = Table[(1 - (-1)^i)/i, {i, 16}]/Pi;
ParametricPlot[outline[a, tmax], {tmax, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above outline was generated as if there were sixteen circles in the model. You can change the number 16 to get another outline.

We can append this function to `Show` inside the original function to draw the outline together with the animation.

```
Show[..., ..., ParametricPlot[outline[a, tmax], {tmax, 0, t}]]
```

We have to make a small change in the call to `Manipulate` because we can't plot from 0 to 0, so we increase the lower bound slightly:

```
Manipulate[FourierAnim[a[[;; j]], t], {t, 0.001, 1}, {j, 1, Length@a, 1}]
```

[image]

### The triangle wave

As for your second question about the triangle wave we have to look at the math. The [Fourier series of the square wave](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSquareWave.html) is
$$
f(x) = \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{i=1,3,5,...}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i}\sin\left(\frac{i\pi x}{L}\right)
$$
and the corresponding code that we used is

```
a = Table[(1 - (-1)^i)/i, {i, 16}]/Pi;
FourierF[a_, t_] := a.Table[Sin[ 2 Pi i t], {i, Length[a]}];
```

Note that the sum in the Fourier series only sums over odd indices. The `1-(-1)^i` part captures this behavior, because it is zero for even `i`. The other part of the formula is `1/i`, and this is the coefficient of the `Sin` function in the Fourier series. We don't have to match the constants, it's enough that what we have is proportional to the Fourier series.

The [Fourier series of the triangle wave](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesTriangleWave.html) is
$$
f(x) = \frac{8}{\pi^2}\sum_{i=1,3,5,...}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{(i-1)/2}}{i^2}\sin\left(\frac{i \pi x}{L}\right).
$$
Like the square wave Fourier series it is a Sin Fourier series that only sums over odd indices. So we can surmise that our expression will have two parts just like above; one part to set the expression to zero for even indices, and one part to match the coefficient. We end up with this:

```
a = Table[(1 - (-1)^i) (-1)^(0.5 i - 0.5)/i^2, {i, 16}]/Pi;
```

where the two parts are `(1 - (-1)^i)` and `(-1)^(0.5 i - 0.5)/i^2`.

Putting this into our code, we get:

[image]

Because the expression sometimes takes on negative values I had to apply `Abs` to the radii of the circle:

```
Circle[{A[[i]], B[[i]]}, a[[i]] // Abs]
```

We can find the expressions corresponding to other Fourier series in the same way.

Comment: What an elegant solution! Thank you for the detailed walk-through, it is very useful and appreciated. Any idea how to make a [triangle wave](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesTriangleWave.html)?

Comment: @BoC. I added a part about that.

Comment: Amazing how the triangle formula accounts for phase inversion every other (odd) harmonic, in order to obtain the regular waveform from the current start point (3Pi/2 in trigonometric direction). By using `(1 - (-1)^i)/i^2` all harmonics start in-phase, but the shape is rotated by Pi/2, making the time domain waveform unrecognizable. Theoretically, this phase change shouldn't affect the way generated tones sound.

Comment: How can phase be changed for sawtooth? The code for different waveforms and their Pi/2 phase change is to be inserted inside the `Table` function: `a = Table[ ... ]/Pi;`  —  
square: `(1-(-1)^i)/i,{i,64}` | phase: `(1-(-1)^i)(-1)^((i-1)/2)/i,{i,64}`  —  
triangle: `(1-(-1)^i)(-1)^((i-1)/2)/i^2,{i,64}` | phase: `(1-(-1)^i)/i^2,{i,64}`  —  
saw: `(1+(-1)^i)/i,{i,65}` | phase: `???`

Comment: @BoC. This is not the appropriate site for the math. If you have further inquiries that are not about *Mathematica*, it is better that you ask on math.SE.

Comment: For anyone interested, the question has been posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849028/extracting-the-sum-from-the-fourier-series-and-expressing-phase-change)

Answer (score 4):

This is an inefficient method based on an answer to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100051/dynamic-epicycles). The other answers are relevant, particularly in relation to changing phase.

Exploiting C.E.'s answer (which I have voted for):

```
fourier[r_, n_] := 
 Module[{fun = 
    Function[x, 
     Accumulate@
      Prepend[ReIm@
        MapThread[#1 Exp[2 Pi I #2 x ] &, {r, Range[Length@r]}], {0, 
        0}]],
   par = Function[t, r.Table[Sin[2 Pi j t], {j, Length@r}]],
   tab, g, h}, tab = Table[fun[j], {j, 0, 1, 1/n}];
  g = Graphics[{White, MapThread[Circle[#1, Abs@#2] &, {Most@#, r}], 
       Red, Point[Most@#], Purple, PointSize[0.04], Point[Last@#], 
       Yellow, Line@tab[[All, -1]], Line@#, Dashed, Red, 
       Line[{Last@#, {5, #[[-1, 2]]}}]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-5, 10}, {-4, 4}}] & /@ tab;
  h = Table[Plot[par[t - s], {s, 5, 7}], {t, 0, 1, 1/n}];
  MapThread[
   Show[#1, #2, Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 500] &, {g, h}]
  ]
wave[n_, type_] := Which[
  type == "square", Table[(1 - (-1)^i)/i, {i, n}],
  type == "sawtooth", Table[(1 + (-1)^i)/i, {i, n}],
  type == "triangle", Table[(1 - (-1)^i) (-1)^((i - 1)/2)/i^2, {i, n}]]
fourieranim[type_, n_, steps_] := fourier[wave[n, type], steps];
```

The following are examples of 8 term series for square, sawtooth and triangular wavses:

[image]

Comment: Your version is very useful since I'm learning through examples here. The code from the question had a way of changing waveforms, from (approximately) square to sawtooth by modifying values according to the commented code. How can other waveforms be generated in your version? And how can the number of harmonics be modified (the initial `j`)?

Comment: @BoC. I suggest looking at documentation, e.g. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FourierTransforms.html.  You can play around. Good luck :)

Comment: Not just the Mathematica manual, but also a math course. The problem with this "triangle wave" rendition is, harmonics don't have amplitudes (circle radiuses) corresponding to the triangle wave function, that is, `A_n=(1/n^2)A_1`. I just managed to get a grip of the first example of the code, and thought that for an advanced user tracing a contour at the point where the dotted horizontal line starts would be a piece of cake: specifying the correct coordinates in the existing `Plot` function, or creating a new one. It's this that I want to learn.

Comment: @BoC.  I am sorry if I have misunderstood. I sincerely apologize. I cannot delete it if you wish.  I currently do not have time. I only posted this answer in the aim of you or others solving. I apologize again. I can happily delete if you wish