# How to add color to a knot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, knots

Is there a way to use a colorscheme to a `KnotData` image?

One way is probably convert it to a parametric form and then use `Colorfunction` with `ParametricPlot3D`. The method is described in J.M.'s answer to [How to create a new “person curve”?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/how-to-create-a-new-person-curve). Although it seems to have some problems with `Trefoil`.

Is there any simpler way to do this?

In summary, I want to use (say) `Colorfunction->Hue` with the output of `KnotData["Trefoil"]`.

> Using J.M.'s method

```
FourierCurve[x_, m_, t_, tol_: 0.01] := Module[{rat = Rationalize[#, tol] &, fc},
fc = Take[Chop[Fourier[x, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]],
       Min[m, Ceiling[Length[x]/2]]];
       2 rat[Abs[fc]].Cos[Pi (2 Range[0, Length[fc] - 1] t - rat[Arg[fc]/Pi])]]

{f[t_], g[t_], h[t_]} = FourierCurve[#, 20, t] & /@ 
  KnotData["FigureEight", "SpaceCurve"]["ValuesOnGrid"];

ParametricPlot3D[{f[t], g[t], h[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> None, 
 Boxed -> False, Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 20}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ViewPoint -> Top] /. 
 Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 1/8, rest]
```

It works nicely with "FigureEight", "SolomonSeal", "Stevedore". (There is a small hole in the red region which can be fixed by adjusting the `PlotRange`).

[image]

When I try with "Trefoil", it returns

> Fourier::fftl: Argument Sin[ValuesOnGrid]+2 Sin[2 ValuesOnGrid] is not a non-empty list or rectangular array of numeric quantities. >>

Using `Tube` works with the data, but coloring is not very flexible in that case.

```
Graphics3D[Tube[(KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"][#]) 
                 & /@ Range[0, 2.1 Pi, Pi/50], 0.1]]
```

[image]

Comment: "it seems" - can you include a picture and corresponding code to show why you think it's unsatisfactory?

Comment: Thanks @J.M. for the comment. I often forget to put tea bag in my tea :)

Comment: The reason it doesn't work on `"Trefoil"` is that actual trigonometric expressions are used for `"SpaceCurve"` instead of interpolating functions as with the other knots.

Comment: a way to color `Tube` is to use `VertexColors`: e.g.,  `Graphics3D[
   Tube[KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"] /@ #, 0.1, 
    VertexColors -> Hue /@ #]] &@Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/50]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the `KnotData` evaluates directly to a parametric curve,

```
KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"]
(* {Sin[#1] + 2 Sin[2 #1], Cos[#1] - 2 Cos[2 #1], -Sin[3 #1]} & *)
```

so that no sampling is necessary.

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"][t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Top,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] /. 
 Line[pts_, rest__] :> Tube[pts, 1/8, rest]
```

[image]

Of course, this was true for "FigureEight" as well.  But the difference is that "FigureEight" like many of the `KnotData` objects, is only stored as an interpolating function.  Since "Trefoil" is not an interpolating function, it does not have the "ValuesOnGrid" property.

Comment: …and in fact the reason I used `FourierCurve[]` on all the other knots was precisely because I wanted simple(?) trigonometric expressions for them like with `"Trefoil"`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Tube` as graphics directive in `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"][t], {t, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotStyle -> Tube[.2]]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"][t], 
   KnotData["SolomonSeal", "SpaceCurve"][t], 
   KnotData["FigureEight", "SpaceCurve"][t]},
 {t, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] @ #4 &), 
 PlotStyle -> {Tube[.25], Tube[.15], Tube[.1]}]
```

[image]