# Extra Curves When Generating From Image

Tags: image-processing, generative-art

Using the method in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/how-to-create-a-new-person-curve) I'm trying to generate a curve for this image:

[image: buzz lightyear]

I've gone ahead and imported it and I'm using `img=Binarize[img~Blur~3]` to blur it a bit, which gives me:

[image: binarized image]

So now I use this code:

```
param[x_, m_, t_] := Module[{f, n = Length[x], nf}, f = Chop[Fourier[x]][[;; Ceiling[Length[x]/2]]];
  nf = Length[f];
  Total[Rationalize[2 Abs[f]/Sqrt[n] Sin[Pi/2 - Arg[f] + 2. Pi Range[0, nf - 1] t], .01][[;; Min[m, nf]]]]]

tocurve[Line[data_], m_, t_] := param[#, m, t] & /@ Transpose[data]

lines = Cases[Normal@ListContourPlot[Reverse@ImageData[img], Contours -> {0.5}], _Line, -1];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[tocurve[#, 25, t] & /@ lines], {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

This finally gives me these curves:

[image: curves]

I can see the outline of Buzz pretty clearly in the center, which is what I want. What's all the extra garbage all over the image and how can I get rid of it in my curves? I'd ideally like the equation generating just the outline of Buzz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process is quite complicated as you can see. The code creates a set of parametric equation which can give you set of discrete plots. You can choose few of them which might work (At least worked in this case).

```
mess = 1;
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[tocurve[#, 25, t] & /@ lines[[1 ;; mess]]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

gives

[image]

Increase the `mess` and you will see more extra things.

In general those small things are supposed to give the inner structure (like the face in a portrait). I think those extra curves are supposed to be Buzz's body part (eyes, helmet, ..) which are dismantled because he is moving at the speed of light.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!