# Make a glyph using the BezierCurve function

Tags: image-processing, symbols, fonts, splines

There are a lot of applications that you make a glyph from a scanned image. *Mathematica* does have fine tools to interpolate curves like the `BezierCurve[]` function. The idea is very simple. Given the group of  2D points (the data),  you calculate the corresponding control points (the  pts) using some algorithm (for an example, please see the documentation for `BezierCurve[]` function). My question is the following:

- Is it possible to make a  function f that converts the contour of a closed image   to a set of points 2D (the data), finds the corresponding control points pts (and saves the resulting glyph to an appropriate format like eps)?

For experiments you could use the following simple line. (I guess that f depends on an additional parameter $n$ for the maximum number of points allowed in data. If $n$ is very big like $n=1000$ the output glyph should be perfect but then it  is  very difficult to calculate the data. So the  value of  $n$ should be small like up to N= 100 or up to $n=50$  different 2D points in data...)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am going to copy-paste [Simon Wood's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17780/8070) of [How to create a new “person curve”?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/how-to-create-a-new-person-curve)

```
param[x_, m_, t_] := Module[{f, n = Length[x], nf},
   f = Chop[Fourier[x]][[;; Ceiling[Length[x]/2]]];
   nf = Length[f];
   Total[Rationalize[2 Abs[f]/Sqrt[n] Sin[Pi/2 - Arg[f] + 
        2. Pi Range[0, nf - 1] t], .01][[;; Min[m, nf]]]]]

tocurve[Line[data_], m_, t_] := param[#, m, t] & /@ Transpose[data]


img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhK3X.png"];

ires = 500; (*Image size to work with*)
img = Binarize[img~ColorConvert~"Grayscale"~ImageResize~ires~Blur~3]~ Blur~3;
lines = Cases[Normal@ListContourPlot[Reverse@ImageData[img], 
              Contours -> {0.5}], _Line, -1];

f[t_] = tocurve[#, 20, t] & /@ lines;
ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> .3]
```

[image]

For complicated curves `f[t]` might be a collection of functions. The second index of `tocurve` is the `N` you are looking for.

To plot it in a different way,

```
Graphics[Polygon[Table[f[t][[1]], {t, 0, 1, 0.01}]]]
```

[image]

Which is much closer to what we start from.

Comment: Thanks for the editing. I try to change tocurve[#, 20, t]  to other value like tocurve[#, 10, t] without much success I will try some other ideas from http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/637/character-edge-finding  I haven't  finished yet but I hope I will have an alternative answer. +1 for your answer!

Comment: You can try increasing the value like 200 or higher.

Comment: @SumitΙ have already done! The results are the same... Have you tried this?

Comment: my bad, I didn't put the definition of `tocurve` in my answer. Sorry for that. It will work now. Use bigger image size (`ires`) along with the argument of `tocurve` if you want more points.