# Make Person Curve from a Picture

Tags: graphics, image-processing, algorithm, generative-art

I recently read this; http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/

In this post, newton curve is made by using the image "curveAnnotatedNewtonImage"(In[61]), but I couldn't figure out how this annotation was done.

Therefore, I would like to ask you the how to extract feature lines from faces to implement the following FFT calculation.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you seen http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/how-to-create-a-new-person-curve?rq=1?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for your comment. Yes, I have seen the post you showed me, but I couldn't find the way in which I can annotate a line from a portrait.