# How to mesh two ParametricPlot3D function and change the line to cuboid

Tags: graphics3d

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u}, {u, 0, 2}, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], PlotRange -> All], 
     ParametricPlot3D[{2 Sin[u], 2 Cos[u], u}, {u, 0, 2}, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], PlotRange -> All]]
```

Hi experts,

I would like to ask:

1) How to make the line be replaced with cuboid so that we can see how it's twisted? I did replace the line with tube, but I cant see how the line is twisted:

[image: figure]

2) What if we want to mesh the two lines with seperate `ParametricPlot3D` as shown above (This is just an example)?

Your answer is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "twisted"? Do you want to visualize the Frenet frame?

Comment: Instead of visualize Frenet Frame, how i wish is to enlarge the curve (in cuboid shape) to see how the curve is twisted.

Comment: The method in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11452) can be used as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69831/moving-polygon-on-path-curve-to-create-3d-shape

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this is what you ask for. It used the Frenet frame of a `curve` in order to map the corners of a square into $\mathbb{R}^3$. Afterwards, these points are connected to form a tube with rectangular cross section.

```
curve = t \[Function] {Sin[t], Cos[t], t};
tangent = t \[Function] Evaluate[Simplify[curve'[t]/Sqrt[curve'[t].curve'[t]]]];
normal = t \[Function] Evaluate[Simplify[tangent'[t]/Sqrt[tangent'[t].tangent'[t]]]];
binormal = t \[Function] Evaluate[Cross[tangent[t], normal[t]]];

radius = 0.2;
crosssection0 = radius {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}};
crosssection = t \[Function] Evaluate[crosssection0.{normal[t], binormal[t]}];
tlist = Subdivide[0., 2. Pi, 1000];

pts = Flatten[Plus[
    Transpose[
     ConstantArray[curve /@ tlist, Length[crosssection0]], {2, 1, 
      3}],
    (crosssection /@ tlist)
    ], 1];
m = Length[crosssection0];
n = Length[tlist];
polys = Partition[Flatten[BlockMap[
     Transpose[{Partition[#[[1]], 2, 1, #[[1, 1]]], 
        Reverse /@ Partition[#[[2]], 2, 1, #[[2, 1]]]}] &,
     Transpose[Table[Range[i, m n, m], {i, 1, m}]],
     2, 1
     ]], 4];

gc = GraphicsComplex[pts, {
   FaceForm[Orange, Darker@Darker@Blue], 
   Specularity[White, 30], EdgeForm[], Polygon[polys]
  }];
Graphics3D[
 gc, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"
 ]
```

[image]

You can do that also with other cross sections. For example,

```
crosssection0 = Times[
   CirclePoints[10.],
   Flatten[Transpose[{
      ConstantArray[radius, 5],
      ConstantArray[0.5, 5]
      }]]
   ];
```

leads to

[image]

**Edit**

I packaged everything into a simple function.

```
ClearAll[plot]
plot[curve_, tlist_, radius_, OptionsPattern[{
    PlotStyle -> {},
    "CrossSection" -> {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}}
    }]] := 
 Module[{tangent, normal, binormal, crosssection, crosssection0, pts, 
   m, n, polys, gc},
  tangent = 
   t \[Function] Evaluate[Simplify[curve'[t]/Sqrt[curve'[t].curve'[t]]]]; 
  normal = t \[Function] 
    Evaluate[Simplify[tangent'[t]/Sqrt[tangent'[t].tangent'[t]]]]; 
  binormal = t \[Function] Evaluate[Cross[tangent[t], normal[t]]];
  crosssection0 = N[OptionValue["CrossSection"]];
  crosssection = 
   t \[Function] 
    Evaluate[radius crosssection0.{normal[t], binormal[t]}];

  pts = Flatten[
    Plus[
     Transpose[ConstantArray[curve /@ tlist, Length[crosssection0]], {2, 1, 3}], 
     (crosssection /@ tlist)
     ], 
    1];
  m = Length[crosssection0];
  n = Length[tlist];
  polys = 
   Partition[
    Flatten[BlockMap[
      Transpose[{Partition[#[[1]], 2, 1, #[[1, 1]]], 
         Reverse /@ Partition[#[[2]], 2, 1, #[[2, 1]]]}] &, 
      Transpose[Table[Range[i, m n, m], {i, 1, m}]], 2, 1]], 4];

  gc = GraphicsComplex[
    pts, {FaceForm[Orange, Darker@Darker@Blue], 
     Specularity[White, 30], EdgeForm[], 
     Sequence @@ Flatten[{OptionValue["PlotStyle"]}], Polygon[polys]}];
  Graphics3D[gc, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
  ]
```

Now you can do things like this:

```
tlist = Subdivide[0., 2. Pi, 250];
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtJoA.png"];
img = Binarize[img~ColorConvert~"Grayscale"~ImageResize~500~Blur~3];
pts = DeleteDuplicates@
   Cases[Normal@
      ListContourPlot[Reverse@ImageData[img], 
       Contours -> {0.5}], _Line, -1][[1, 1]];
center = Mean@MinMax[pts] & /@ Transpose@pts;
pts = # - center & /@ pts[[;; ;; 20]];


Show[
 plot[u \[Function] {Sin[u], Cos[u], u}, tlist, 0.15,
  "CrossSection" -> 0.01 Reverse[pts],
  PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Pink, Blend[{Red, Blue}, 0.5]]
  ],
 plot[u \[Function] {2 Sin[u], 2 Cos[u], u}, tlist, 0.2]
 ]
```

[image]

I got the elephant from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171756/38178) by [anderstood](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18767).

Comment: Ok, is that mean i can only draw it with Graphic3D only?

Comment: How about meshing two ParametricPlor3D curves as shown above?

Comment: I don't know of a built-in way to do it with, e.g. `ParametricPlot3D`. But `Graphics3D` is what is internally used in all 3D plots.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: The [Bishop frame](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167614) should be usable here, too.

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear from the image what sort of twisting is desired.  The image in the OP, to my eye, does not reflect the torsion of the Frenet Frame.  In any case, here is a way using `Tube` with the method option `"TubePoints" -> 4` to get a square cross section (see, for example, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126508/4999)):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u], u/5 Cos[u]}, {u, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 4}
  ] /. Line[p_] :> Tube[p, 0.2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's a mesh of a torus (zoomed in image shown):

```
Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@
    Table[{4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 
        4 + Sin[v]} /. {u -> 2 u, v -> u + 3 v} // Evaluate,
     {v, 0, Pi, Pi/8}],
   {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], PlotRange -> All,
    Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 4}],
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@
    Table[{4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 
        4 + Sin[v]} /. {u -> 2 u - v, v -> 3 v} // Evaluate,
     {u, 0, Pi, Pi/8}],
   {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], 
   PlotRange -> All, Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 4}]
  ] /. Line[p_] :> Tube[p, 0.1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]