# setting size of images which are result of TextRecognize

Tags: image, dataset, ocr

Im learning Mathematica and the Wolfram language for shot time by myself. Its a pain for me that many settings are somehow hidden. Now I spent hours to find solution for something I already did with success, but now I can not remeber.
When I disassemble a scanned text by use of TextRecognize up to the level of Character (but the same is for Word) then the cropped sub-images of individual letters have different (automatic) size. For me this is nonsense to see a dot in simillar size like character let say "a". I would like to get the cropped images of letters in original size or in same size.
Here example of code:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vb9o.png"];
```

[image]

```
dsChars = TextRecognize[image, "Character", {"Image", "Text"}] // Dataset
```

Which brings this result:

[image: resulting_dataset]

I would like to see the characters in the first collumn being of simillar size - for example the "e" in 5th row to be same height like the "m" in 6th row ...
I will appreciate your time and effort for any advice and help.

EDIT 16.5.18 18:18 CEST
For to show what I mean when I say that I want to see the sub-images in proportion, here is a sample what I can do with a **list** of sub-images:

```
Image[Normal[dsChars[{1, 2}, 1]], Magnification -> 1]
```

[image: images_in_proportion]
here the "M" is in proportion to "a"

However how to change appearance of the sub-images in the first collumn of the "printout" of the **dataset** dsChars ?

EDIT 2 17.5.18, 17:24 CEST
I edited the title - removed unnecessary last part " /and potentially for one column of Dataset / " of the title which was too long

Comment: Have you checked `ImageResize`? It would help us help you to have a complete minimal example to work on.

Comment: anderstood - ImageResize for the example "scanned_text"? That image is only 463x286 pix. I dont know why the image didnt show. Here is the link which the editor created in the question source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vb9o.png

Comment: No, for the images that you want to have similar sizes. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @anderstood - thank you for editing my question for the input image to be seen; Im totally inexperienced with the interface here on the forum. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set `ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1` for the `Dataset`:

```
Style[Dataset[dsChars2], ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: oh great! that was what I already found somwhere months ago, but wasnt able to find it again; perfect!

Comment: again - unfortunately I cannot mark your answer as usefull as the system tells me I dont have enough reputation points; can somebody do it for me on Aleksey Popkov and SquareOne answers, please?

Comment: Aleksey, I tried it now but it does not work on my Raspberry PI3 Mathematica (v. 11.2.0.0) - result of the Style is equal to the previous appearance of the dataset :(    ; but Im sure something like that should work

Comment: @CJoe It dosen't work for me either (v11.2 or 11.3 with OSX) ...

Comment: @CJoe Please try `Style[Dataset[dsChars2], 
 GraphicsBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 1}]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov - unfortunately this didnt help either; By the way is it necessary applying to dsChars2? I would preffer working with the direct result of TextRecognize which is dsChars here

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime I found quite acceptable answer (solution 1) to my question and SquareOne tuned it to two additional, perfect answers (solution 2 and 3).

For this case:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vb9o.png"];
dsChars = TextRecognize[image, "Character", {"Image", "Text"}]
```

my solution is (solution 1):

```
Transpose[{Image[dsChars[[All, 1]], Magnification -> 1], dsChars[[All, 2]]}] // Dataset
```

But @SquareOne simplified this solution very nice to (solution 2):

```
dsChars /. x_Image :> Image[x, Magnification -> 1]// Dataset
```

which seems to me much better solution as it does not need Transpositions.

Also @SquareOne draw my attention to the fact that if the "image" which I let TextRecognized was already provided with property of Magnification->1, then the resulting sub-images of individual characters will come out from the Textrecognize properly.

Therefore this is an equally perfect solution too (solution 3):

```
image = Image[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vb9o.png"], Magnification -> 1];
dsChars = TextRecognize[image, "Character", {"Image", "Text"}]// Dataset
```

All those solutions are giving following, for me perfectly reasonable output:
[image]

If @SquareOne created the Solution 2 and Solution 3 as his separate answers, I would be happy marking them both as perfect answers for my question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, maybe this:

given

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vb9o.png"]
dsChars = TextRecognize[image, "Character", {"Image", "Text"}]
```

then

```
 MapAt[ImagePad[#, 
    Transpose@
     Through[{Floor, Ceiling}[({30, 30} - ImageDimensions[#])/2]]] &, 
  dsChars, {All, 1}] // Dataset
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: yes, such appearance of sub-images I was searching for

Comment: In the meantime I have found following solution: `Transpose[{Image[dsChars[[All, 1]], Magnification -> 1],dsChars[[All, 2]]}] // Dataset` , but both your and mine solutions seem to me too complicated; there must be something to say directly to TextRecognize how the result should be presented or to say to the dataset table (printout) what properties should have the images in first row.

Comment: anyway thank you SquareOne

Comment: unfortunately I cannot mark your answer as usefull as it tells me that I dont have enough reputation point

Comment: @CJoe You actually found the solution ! In `Image` the option `Magnification` is set to `Automatic` by default. You should self answer to your own post (it's OK to do so). A more simple way to do it : `dsChars /. x_Image :> Image[x, Magnification -> 1] `

Comment: @CJoe Actually there is even a more simple solutio, just after importing do : `image = Image[image, Magnification -> 1]` !

Comment: @CJoe +1 you can vote now

Comment: thanks for points :)  ; And your (first) simplification is great! No Transpositions, perfect. And its the way of writing code I have to learn. Thanks. The second simplification seems very interesting to me - does it meanthat the sub-images have inherited the Magnification property from the original Image, so TextRecognize did not have any influence? Then it starts to fit together to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CJoe Yes, for the second simplification i thought that the inheritance would work and it did. My post here is not responding your question as it modifies the images but I will leave it  just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vb9o.png"]
dsChars = TextRecognize[image, "Character", {"Image", "Text"}]
dsChars2 = Transpose[{ImageResize[#, {20}] & /@ dsChars[[All, 1]], 
dsChars[[All, 2]]}] // Dataset
```

[image]

This forces each thumbnail to have a maximal width or height of at most 20 pixels. You could also want to set a height of 20 pixels for each e.g.

Comment: thank you anderstood, but I need the characters to be simillar in meaning like proportional or how to say it - capital "M" should be higher than "a" not the same height as in your result. And  I think ImageResize changes the real size of those images. I only need to see the sub-images all in same "resolution", And as I understand those really are in the origiinal resolution. Only they are presented n the dataset table in a strange "automatic" sizes.

Comment: Im sure there is some properties setting or what to change appearance of the images in the dataset table, in past I already suceeded to have same sizes of the characters there. But I cannot find this setting again.  I also succeeded to change appearance of the character images in a list of them -> `Image[TextRecognize[image, "Word", {"Image"}], 
 Magnification -> 1] ` but Im not able to do this with a list of lists like the dataset above.

Comment: Mmh, I see. You can check that `TextRecognize` actually changes the dimensions of the images, that has nothing to do with `Dataset`:  `dsChars = TextRecognize[image, "Character", {"Image", "Text"}]` then `ImageDimensions /@ dsChars[[All, 1]]`.

Comment: You can get the bounding boxes with: `dsChars = TextRecognize[image, "Character", {"Image", "Text", "BoundingBox"}]`. You can check that the boxes have different heights: `Show[image, Graphics@dsChars[[All, 3]]]`. So, would you like to change the rectangles so that the have all the same heights, and then extract the corresponding images?

Comment: yes, sure the boxes have different sizes because for example capital "M" takes more space than small "a". I dont want to lose these real dimensions and I want to see the sub-images in proportions like they were cutted from the original image.

Comment: I now see that I formulated unprecisely "... then the cropped sub-images of individual letters have different (automatic) size..." in my question. Instead I meant that the cropped sub-images are **shown** in the resulting dataset with changed dimensions, and are unproportional one to each other so for example upper case letter is shown the same height like lower case letter.

Comment: @CJoe I get it now, and I see you got some great answers! Perfect!

Comment: I apologise for posting this "answer"
but im new to this website and im kinda lost
can you help me contact anderstood (he answered on this question)
im trying to reach him but apparently you cant reach users on this site and you cant comment before you answer enough questions
if you are anderstood and you are reading this
im trying to reach you to ask for your help on a question you answered about 1 year ago
its the how to create a new persons curve
im kinda lost and if you would either teach me or help me turn a persons picture into a curve I would be so grateful
I know I sound like a choosin

Comment: @theme You can contact a user with @<username> . Possibly on the chat. The best would be to ask a new question by showing what you have tried. I the meanwhile you might be interested in this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/how-to-create-a-new-person-curve or [this](https://blog.wolfram.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/).